# java type for javascript anonymous function

Tags: java, graalvm

What data type will the javascript function like

```
(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  host.somethingsomething();
}
```

be cast to in Java?

I have host objects for `event` and for `host`.

I don't know how to turn that ^^ into a function I can run in Java.

Comment: Did you try getting the real object at run time and inspect its class (and probably the classes superclass/ interfaces using reflection)?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy I don't know how to do that